# Data binding - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am working with Visual Studio 2010.

Scenario:

I have 2 comboboxes. 
Contents of first combobox:

PC

DB...

Contents of Second combobox:

Password reset

Hardware problem

SQL

My question:

When I select 'PC' in the first combo box I want 'Password Reset' and 'Hardware Problem' to show up.

When I select 'DB' in first combobox I want 'SQL' to show up in the second combo box.

Does anyone know how I can bind data from one combo box to the other ?

Also when I click on 'DB' ->'SQL' then a 3rd list box with data under these two combo items should be populated.

I feel this relates to data binding but not sure how to go about it.

ANy idea or link I could refer to??

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a Win Forms app, ASP, WPF, or something else?  That will greatly change the answer...

Comment: Its the basic windows application.Basically trying to create a chain: if 1st category is selected- 2nd will get populated accordingly and as per second the 3rd will get populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question is very broad. Basically you have nothing besides the problem. So it's hard for anyone to give you good advise because it would amount to quite a few lines of code. So I try to give you a high-level overview.

The easiest way (without any desing-patterns or some advanced stuff) is just to put all you choices hardwired in combobox1. Then listen for the selecteditem-change event and fill combobox2 acording to what was selected.
Rinse/Repeat with your optional combobox3.

To move on you can pull the values out of database-tables or config files instead of hardwiring them.

And finally you could move on to MVVM or a similiar pattern to to the theselction in a viewmodel and the representation in a view.

For now think about the first one and try to implement it - should be quite easy.

Comment: thank you. I was just making a very basic prototype and needed a start. This was very helpful.